# How to draw/create GDI+ on MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+

I have a MFC Application with Dialog Based. I created a GDI+ Object from resource by using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI).

MyDlg.cpp:

```
BOOL CSetupDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
        ...
}
```

void MyFunction():

```
CGdiPlusBitmapResource* pBitmap = new CGdiPlusBitmapResource;
if (pBitmap->Load(ID_SPL_LG))
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc);
    graphics.DrawImage(*pBitmap, 0, 0);
    //It is loaded . I checked with messagebox and its in here.
}
Invalidate(); //Not sure if necessary.
```

Now, Form/Dialog shows nothing. No image inserted nor attached.

Now, i tried few things to add this image to the dialog but i am unable to do it.

What i tried is `GDIObject.Create()`, `CStatic.Create()` and `PictureControl.Create()`

All i want to do is insert this image to the dialog.

Any idea or showing path is appreciated.

Comment: You should only create a `CPaintDC` in response to a `WM_PAINT` message, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to override the `OnPaint` method that responds to the `WM_PAINT` message in your dialog. Normally you don't need to do this because the dialog doesn't need to paint anything, it just lets the controls that are contained on it paint themselves.

Move the code you show into the OnPaint handler.

Do *not* call the default OnPaint from your own handler.

Do *not* call `Invalidate` from within the OnPaint handler or you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: I did what you said. Move the code to `OnPaint` Handler, Removed the `Invalidate()` and di not call `OnPaint` manually. Still no errors but also it does not show any image. (Both local file or resource :)) I am definitely missing something but cpouldn't find what it is.

Comment: @xangr, you may need to put an `Invalidate` somewhere else to trigger the OnPaint.

Comment: See, i knew i did misss something :) Yes, it is worked now. Thank you Mark! I really appreciated it.